# Is there a screen alternative for a DSLR predating Live-View for photo review in the field?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, image-review

Is it possible to obtain something with a screen about postcard-sized that can either plug into my Canon EOS 20D camera and act as a larger screen, or alternatively will accept the CF card from the camera via a card reader, to check for focus accuracy. I dont want to be carrying my laptop miles from the car.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Canon 20D doesn't have live view and that makes it a little hard but I guess it shouldn't be that hard to hook a bigger monitor to it.

I just looked up the B&H quickly and I found this portable monitor which has **analog inputs**:

**[Vello RigVision 9" HD Camera Monitor](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/759026-REG/Vello_CM_9HD_Rigvision_9_HD_Camera.html)**
It has many different inputs and I guess you should be able to connect to your camera.

You can find many other similar products with analog input **[here](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/On-Camera-Field-Monitors/ci/1984/N/4206279312)** on B&H.

Also, because Epson P-3000 is discontinued, you can check other similar products, such as [**Sanho HyperDrive multimedia player and storage device**](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/887229-REG/Sanho_shdcsudma2160_160GB_HyperDrive_COLORSPACE_UDMA2.html).

Comment: For that matter, an older pocket TV or clamshell DVD player ought to do the trick. Since they don't receive digital transmission or have HDMI in, they should be littering the yard sales (and eBay and so forth).

Comment: The only thing I am skeptic about and why I did not go with that suggestion is the display quality over analog NTSC/PAL signal which is heavily sub-sampled. I used to review my photos in hotel rooms when I had a 5 MP camera 10 years ago do not recall how it looked zoomed in.

Answer (score 2):

The [EPSON P3000](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/jsp/Product.do?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&sku=B31B186002#0) is probably what you are looking for. It also does backups too as a bonus. It has a 4" LCD and can show both JPEG and RAW images from a Compact-Flash card. You can zoom into images to check focus.

Just note that because it is hard-drive based, it does not work above 10,000' of altitude which can be a concern for some and irrelevant for others. I have not tried but the problem would go away if you manage to open it and substitute an SSD inside.

Comment: Epsom 3000 discontinued unfortunately

Comment: Try eBay or similar site for a used one. Your 20D too is discontinued :) Most importantly, once you upgrade your camera with a Live-View capable one, there will be better options available such as an [HDMI monitor](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15750/is-it-possible-to-get-a-larger-screen-for-live-view-for-precise-manual-focus/15752#15752). This lets you see details without taking the card out of the camera and even preview while focusing right on a big screen.

Comment: For something new, look into [these](http://www.hypershop.com/HyperDrive-COLORSPACE-UDMA-s/64.htm). Never seen one in-person though, so I cannot vouch for them like the P3000. Maybe Espon has a new revision, I would check with them first.

Comment: @Itai I just noticed that you had suggested the HyperDrive too, do you know any similar storage/player with SSD? also I guess they could use a portable monitor with analog input too, right?

Comment: @Omne - No but doing your own substitution may be possible. You would have to write to the manufacturer to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there are a number of smartphone and tablet options (none of which I've needed to try personally, but they may give you some ideas):

- use an iPad with a [CF card adapter](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/03/finally-a-compact-flash-reader-for-ipad/)
- use a [SD to CF adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052GZNY0) in your camera to record images onto SD cards instead of CF; you can then use the [iPad Camera Connection Kit](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC531ZM/A/apple-ipad-camera-connection-kit) to read images from the SD card on your iPad
- as above, use an appropriate adapter to record onto SD or Micro-SD cards which can be read by many Android tablets
- use an [Eye-Fi](http://www.eye.fi) card in the camera and connect to it using Eye-Fi's [Android](http://www.eye.fi/products/android) or [iPhone](http://www.eye.fi/products/iphone) apps

Comment: Eye-Fi does not work with a 20D, even with an adapter.

Comment: Ipad is I feel to big and delicate to be wandering around rough countryside with.

Comment: Stick it in a ruggedized case, it'd be a great tool for the OP's purpose, same would go for a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in something called the [Z-Finder](http://www.zacuto.com/z-finder-dslr-viewfinder), which is designed for this purpose. Only its not electronic, but a viewer/magnifier for your LCD screen. Basically for Professional Chimping :)

http://www.zacuto.com/z-finder-dslr-viewfinder